# How to read protected config values in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-config

Hii...

I would like to read protected database values from config file in datagrid file, plz help how can I do that...thanx in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by `protected database values`?

Comment: @John - when i am trying to access as $db = Zend_Registry::get('db'); it says protected and access denied when trying to extract the db config values, what does that mean ?? plz suggest if any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
```

*Usually* what this code does is get at the DB variable in your registry. This code does not access the config file.

If you want to get at the config file use,

```
Zend_Registry::get('config')->YOUR->KEY->GOES->HERE
```